# VBA Trying to check for a value in column and if there copy another cells value to a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data in a sheet that i am looking to make some adjustments to. I have a single column called "S/R" which will have one of two values in it [Serving OR Returning]. If the value is serving i want to copy the value from a column called "1stServeX" to a new column i have added i called "Server 1st Serve X".

I have written the code below but am beginning to trip myself up and also cannot finish the last part. I am a novice and so have been using other pieces of code i have gained previously to try and piece it together, which is why i need some help.

If i can get this going then i can simply repeat it for all the "Returner" option and all the other columns i need to split too.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

```
Public Sub splitServerCoordinates()
    'Set a constant for the title of the Server Column
    Const HEADER_SR As String = "S/R"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("transition")
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim COL_SR As Long
    Dim COL_TARGET As Long
    Dim COL_CURRENT As Long

    'Find the Column Numbers of the columns we are looking for
    strSearch = "S/R"

    Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        COL_SR = aCell.Column
    End If
    
    strSearch = "1stServeX"

    Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        COL_CURRENT = aCell.Column
    End If
    
    strSearch = "Server 1st Serve X"

    Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        COL_TARGET = aCell.Column
    End If
    
    Dim theUsedRange As Range
    Dim SRRange As Range
    Dim aPlayer As Range
    Dim serving As String
    Dim returning As String
    Dim theCounter As Long
    Dim theSequence As Long
    
    ws.Select
    
    ' clear out the Target column and add the header again
    Set theUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Intersect(theUsedRange, Range(Columns(COL_TARGET), Columns(COL_TARGET))).ClearContents
    Columns(COL_SR).Range("A1").Value = HEADER_SR
    
    ' reset the used range just in case
    Set theUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    ' Get the used range for the S/R column
    Set SRRange = Intersect(theUsedRange, Columns(COL_SR))
    
    'Set value to compare to
    serving = "Serving"
    
    ' Loop through the S/R column
    For Each aPlayer In SRRange
        ' ignore the header row
        If aPlayer <> HEADER_SR Then
            ' if we are serving then copy the value from COL_CURRENT to COL_TARGET
            If aPlayer = serving Then
                    aPlayer.Offset(-1, COL_TARGET - COL_).Value = STUCK - HERE
            End If
        End If
    Next aPlayer
End Sub
```

Comment: Please replace `STUCK - HERE` with your attempted code

Comment: What is the question? What is and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Some refactoring to pull out the column header location parts, and a few other tweaks.  Untested, but should get you there.

```vb
Public Sub splitServerCoordinates()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim COL_SR As Long
    Dim COL_TARGET As Long
    Dim COL_CURRENT As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("transition")
    
    'Find the Column Numbers of the columns we are looking for
    COL_SR = HeaderColumnNumber(ws.Rows(1), "S/R")
    COL_CURRENT = HeaderColumnNumber(ws.Rows(1), "1stServeX")
    COL_TARGET = HeaderColumnNumber(ws.Rows(1), "Server 1st Serve X", True) 'add if not found
    
    'exit if missing any required columns
    If COL_SR = 0 Or COL_CURRENT = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Missing 'S/R' and/or '1stServeX' !"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'reset target column
    ws.Columns(COL_TARGET).ClearContents
    ws.Cells(1, COL_TARGET).Value = "Server 1st Serve X"
    
    'loop rows
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, COL_SR), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, COL_SR).End(xlUp)).Cells
        If c.Value = "Serving" Then
            ws.Cells(c.Row, COL_TARGET).Value = ws.Cells(c.Row, COL_CURRENT).Value
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub

'Find a header position on a row, with option to add it if not found
'  Returns zero if header is not found and option to add was not set
Function HeaderColumnNumber(rng As Range, hdr As String, _
                            Optional AddIfMissing As Boolean = False) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set rng = rng.Cells(1).EntireRow 'only want a full row to look in
    Set f = rng.Find(What:=hdr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        HeaderColumnNumber = f.Column 'found: return column
    Else
        'not found: do we add it, or return zero?
        If AddIfMissing Then
            With rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
                .Value = hdr
                HeaderColumnNumber = .Column
            End With
        Else
            HeaderColumnNumber = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm having a play around with it at the moment and updating it to suit the different columns i have. I'm not sure if your HeaderColumnNumber function is completely working though. It always puts the same header in the columns it adds. Am i doing something wrong? I have added more columns for it to find. Thanks again @TimWilliams

Comment: That function works for me - I'm not sure what you're seeing exactly?  It can only insert the header `hdr` which is passed to the function